# Automatically updated the textbox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

i have this image in my form.
[image]
.When i select the value from my combo box enter the value in my text box and click save...i want to have the value in my text box to do some calculations as i hit the save button for the value selected in my combo box but im not sure which properties in my access form to do the calculations... like if i have monthly selected in my combo box
enter 4 in my tex tbox when i hit save button the value 4 in my text box should be 4(depart * 2) wich is 8

Answer (score 0):

Open your form in design view, right click your save button and select property.
In property sheet select **Event** tab and in **On Click** event select **[Event Procedure]**

and click the small button **...** in front of it. In VBA you can write your calculation and save the record. here's an example

```
textBox1= textBox1 * 2          ' you can assign any calculation you need
If Me.Dirty then Me.Dirty=False ' Save the record
```